# How to remove response header using Outbound Rules in iis?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, url-rewrite-module

Hi I have developed web application and hosted in iis7.5. I am trying to hide server details from response header. I am following `https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varunm/2013/04/23/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/` url rewrite approach. I have followed all the steps however my response header such as server name still visible in case of PUT and DELETE request. It works fine for GET and POST methods. I am not sure how to edit outbound rule in order to hide the server name? I am struggling lot to fix this.May i get some help to fix this? thank you.

I have below code in web.config

```
  <rewrite>    
  <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
    <rule name="Remove Server header">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

Also i have below code in web.config.

```
  <verbs>
                    <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false" />
                    <add verb="TRACE" allowed="false" />
                    <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="DELETE" allowed="false" />
                    <add verb="PARCH" allowed="false" />
                    <add verb="MOVE" allowed="false" />
                    <add verb="COPY" allowed="false" />
                    <add verb="LOCK" allowed="false" />
                    <add verb="UNLOCK" allowed="false" />
                    <add verb="PROPFIND" allowed="false" />
                    <add verb="PROPPATCH" allowed="false" />
                    <add verb="MKCOL" allowed="false" />
                    <add verb="SEARCH" allowed="false" />
                </verbs>
```

[image: Edit Outbound rule]

Screenshot below showing response header for PUT request.
[image]

Below is the conditional tab.
[image]

Comment: As this happens conditionally can you show us if anything is filled in conditions tab?

Comment: Thank you ramesh. I have added screen shot above.

Comment: Conditions is still collapsed in the new image

Comment: Sorry. I have added it again. Let me know if this is visible now.

Comment: Yes I can see that there are no conditions. Can you check if there are any other rules present before  which handles PUT/DELETE and stops the processing of subsequent rules?

Comment: I have added few lines of code in web.config before. I have updated above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156064/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-ramesh).